# ZK : Design Pattern : Paging through large amounts of data?

Tags: java, ajax, zk

I would like some advice on how to tackle paging and sorting through large amounts of data.

At the moment, I retrieve all our user data and stick it in a listbox. This is great for now, but when we have 100 000 users, I don't want to populate a listbox with 100 000 users, nor have a collection on the server with 100 000 users on it.

What would you recommend is a good approach to do this?

Should I keep a ConnectedRecordset and pass that to the Listbox. Does ZK have the capability to manage the data and the connection?

~ OR ~

Would it be better to manually look for page events, and repopulate the listbox with the second set of data, only pulling say 10 rows at a time?

Also, when I want to allow a user to sort by a column, then surely one needs to requery the data from the database.

What is the correct way to challenge this? Please offer advice or links to articles.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the tutorial of [Sorting huge data using ZK](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/March/Sorting_huge_data_using_ZK) and [Handling huge data using ZK](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2009/July/Handling_huge_data_using_ZK)